# How to connect multiple sockets to sails in test

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I have a messaging controller setup in sails.js and want to test it with multiple clients to see if the pub/sub code works. I set up a test file

```
var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');
var sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');
var socket1 = socketIOClient;
var client1 = sailsIOClient(socket1);
var socket2 = socketIOClient;
var client2 = sailsIOClient(socket2);
var socket3 = socketIOClient('http://localhost:1337', {'force new connection': true});
var client3 = sailsIOClient(socket2);
...
```

- `client1.socket.get...` works and says it is subscribed.
- `client1.socket.post...` works and posts a message to the DB.

So I want to test that a client can receive the notification when a new message is posted. However, when I post from either client1 or client2, it posts from both. Essentially, they are linked to the same socket object or something like that, but I don't know where. So I want to connect multiple sockets, and I've tried variations like socket3 and client3, but get the following problem:

- `client3.socket.get...` and `client3.socket.post...` and other variations (forceNew, multiplexing, etc.) each hang up and don't resolve.

Example of hang up:

```
sails.log('posting...');
client3.socket.post('/v1.0/messaging', data, function(body, JWR){
  sails.log('posted');
  done();
});
```

Only `posting...` is logged in this way, but `posted` is logged if using `client1` or `client2`.

---

**My question:**
How can I connect multiple clients to my sails api to test if my pub/sub controller works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but you could try this

```
var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');
var sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');

// Instantiate the socket client (`io`)
var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
// prevents socket to connect with it's default origin
io.sails.autoConnect = false


// Ask the client to create two socket connections
var socket1 = io.sails.connect('http://localhost:1337');
var socket2 = io.sails.connect('http://localhost:1337');

// Test it
socket1.get(url, data, cb)
socket1.post(url, data, cb)
socket2.get(url, data, cb)
socket2.post(url, data, cb)

// If you want to configure and use the "eager" instance
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337'; 
io.socket.get(url, data, cb)
```

This way, you would [create several SailsSocket instance](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/master/dist/sails.io.js#L985) instead of using the ["eager" instance](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/master/dist/sails.io.js#L992-L1004).

When you use `sails.io.js` in a browser, `io.socket` contains the socket instance (called "eager instance" in the comments) which will automatically try to connect using the host that the js file was served from. `io.sails.connect()` allows you to create other instances.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate the explanation and links to the source code showing why it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for actual version of socket.io should be

```
//first socket
var socket1 = socketIOClient('http://localhost:1337', {'forceNew: true});
//second socket
var socket2 = socketIOClient('http://localhost:1337', {'forceNew: true});
```

See socket.io docs http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-1-2-0/#

Comment: I tried this, but it had the same result as `'multiplex':false` and `'force new connection': true` - see the example I just added above. Any reason this might be happening?